# Minificação no Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, minificação

Alguém sabe como minificar arquivos js e css em tempo de execução.
Por exemplo : No arquivo Html , a chamada ao arquivo Javascript está assim :

```html
<script src="~/Content/Site/js/funcoes.js"></script>
```

Gostaria que fosse gerado um arquivo minificado dese script no momento da execução da aplicação, isso seria possível ?

Comment: Quando dizes _"o momento da execução da aplicação"_ queres dizer "no momento em que o ficheiro é pedido ao servidor"? Que linguagem tens no servidor?

Comment: Você precisa fazer isso diretamente no ambiente do servidor. Se você estiver utilizando PHP, aqui tem uma função para minificar css, js e html: https://gist.github.com/tovic/d7b310dea3b33e4732c0

Comment: Sim, no caso eu vou subir o html chamando os arquivos normalmente. e quero que no servidor eles sejam minificados.

Answer (score 1):

Dessa forma voce minifica o javascript e o css

```
var htmlReplace = require('gulp-html-replace') // troca os textos dentro do html
,uglify = require('gulp-uglify') // ninifica js
,usemin = require('gulp-usemin')              /
,cssmin = require('gulp-cssmin') // minifica o tamanho do css

gulp.task('usemin', function() {
  return gulp.src('dist/**/*.html')
    .pipe(usemin({
      js: [uglify],
      css: [cssmin]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

No index.html deve comentar para mostrar ao gulp htmlReplace onde estao os aquivos que vao ser minificado

exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]